# Подскажите где здесь переменная

Tags: php

Есть такой код

```
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo $row["category"]; ?>">
```

Куда идёт значение `<?php echo $row["category"]; ?>`

Вопрос возможно тупой, но как то так...

Comment: Идет в html-код.

Comment: Всмысле, идёт в name или в category ?

Comment: Идет в то место, где стоит код. Т.е. в ``value="вот-сюда"``.

Comment: в значение атрибута value

Comment: Откройте исходный код сгенеренной страницы и вопросов станет меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Представьте, что вы создали инпут:

```
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="2">
```

Ваш input содержит значение 2.
Теперь ваш пример:

```
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo $row["category"] ?>">
```

Тот же самый инпут, только в value у вас хранится уже не 2, а то, что хранится в `$row["category"]`. Допустим, у вас там 5. Значит:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="category" value="5">
```

И echo там не нужно.

```
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php $row["category"] ?>">
```

Вот так верно.